# How do I correctly write a for loop with conditional if statements?

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a for loop that takes a list of numbers, and a desired number and output a list of multiples from the list. I have done so with this code below:

```
    def multiples(list_of_num, desired):
        for i in (list_of_num):
        if i%desired== 0:
            print(i, end='')
```

This code above works, but I also want to protect against a user putting in

```
multiples([], 0)
```

I would also like to output "[]" if there are not multiple present in list_of_num.

When I write conditional statements the program outputs undesirable values. Here is everything I have as well as a sample of an undesired output.

```
    def multiples(list_of_num, desired):
        for i in (list_of_num):
            if i%desired == 0:
                print(i, end='')
            if i%desired== 1:
                print("[]")
            if list_of_num == [] or desired == 0:
                print("No numbers provided")
```

Output:

```
multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2)
[]
2[]
4[]
6[]
8[]
10
```

Desired output:

```
multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2)
2
4
6
8
10
```

or even better

```
multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Please include the expected output, not just the actual (incorrect) output. Also, if the output should be a list, why are you using `print` instead of making a list?

Comment: Try appending numbers(multiples) rather than printing them at each iteration. That way it will be simple to see if the list is empty/ or it has numbers and print at the end.

Comment: `if not list_of_num and not desired: return []; else: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def multiples(list_of_num, desired):

    if list_of_num == [] or desired == 0:
        print("No numbers provided")
        return []

    return [i for i in list_of_num if i % desired == 0]

print(multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2))
```

output:

> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

```
print(multiples([], 2))
```

output:

> No numbers provided
>
> []

without list comprehension:

```
def multiples(list_of_num,desired):
    final = []
    if list_of_num == [] or desired == 0:
        print("No numbers provided")
        return []
    for i in list_of_num:
        if i % desired == 0:
            final.append(i)
    return final
```

Comment: is there a way I can further break down the following line `return [i for i in list_of_num if i % desired == 0]`  into more, but simpler lines? for example could I extract the `i for i` into a for loop line separate from the if expression?

Comment: yeah sure, this is a list comprehension but it does exactly the same as going over the values in the list and append to a new list if a curtain condition is met and then return the new list

Comment: @xhobo6 have a look I added a part without the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Check if [] or 0 are passed as arguments before the loop. If they aren't, then execute the loop:

```
def multiples(list_of_num, desired):
    if list_of_num == [] or desired == 0:
        print("No numbers provided")
    else:
        for i in (list_of_num):
            if i%desired == 0:
                print(i, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

def multiples(list_of_num, desired):
    if list_of_num == [] or desired == 0:
        return "No numbers provided"
    else:
        list_of_num=np.array(list_of_num)
        return list_of_num[list_of_num%desired==0]

print(multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2))
#outputs: [ 2  4  6  8 10]

print(multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 23))
#outputs: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is not wrong
If I well understood your problem, something like that should be better:

```
def multiples(list_of_num, desired):
    multiple_list=[] 
    if len(list_of_num) ==0 or desired==0:
        print("No numbers provided")
    else:
        for i in (list_of_num):
            if i%desired == 0:
                multiple_list.append(i)
        print(multiple_list)
```

Result for multiples([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 2):
[2,4,6,8,10]

Result for multiples([1,3,5,7,9], 2):
[]